# Subclassed UIView not visible, however content is visible

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, pure-layout

I subclassed UIView: http://pastebin.com/MVk1XmPS and when I add it to another view of a UIViewController:

```
self.myView = MyView.newAutoLayoutView()
self.myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(self.myView)
```

the red background is missing. It seems that `myView` has no width and height. However the content is visible:

[image: foto 07 11 14 23 12 36]

I have to hard code the dimension:

```
self.myView.autoSetDimensionsToSize(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

but shouldn't it grow automatically by the size of the content? I use swift, xcode6.1 and iOS8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views do not automatically grow to fit their content. If you enable `clipsToBounds` on your view, you will see the content disappear. Alternatively, if you put a button as part of your content, you will see it but be unable to interact with it because it is outside of its `superview`'s bounds.

In your subclass, you could implement the `sizeToFit` or `sizeThatFits:` methods, but these are not going to be automatically called by the system. You should consider assigning constraints for your view in your storyboard. If you're not using a storyboard, you will need to assign a frame in your `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews` method.

Storyboards will also like your custom view better if you implement `intrinsicContentSize`.

Comment: +1 thank you, implementing intrinsicContentSize did the trick!